# Excel VBA userform - show relevent teams in a combobox from the username function

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want a combobox to only show the relevant teams for that user. To help explain I have a textbox which is filled with the function application.username(textbox1.value = application.username) this is in the initialize event.

I also have a lookup sheet which has all the usernames and the teams they manage the as some users will manage multiple teams.

The only way I can sort of get this to work is to use 2 comboboxs with offset lookups which can result in over 50 named ranges for every user example of code Lookup code on sheet will be `=OFFSET(LOOKUP!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(LOOKUP!$A:$A))`

code on the combbox1 change event the rowsource is set to the first named range called users

```
Dim X As Integer
X = ComboBox1.ListIndex
Select Case X
Case Is = 0
ComboBox2.RowSource = "South"
Case Is = 1
ComboBox2.RowSource = "North"
Case Is = 2
ComboBox2.RowSource = "East"
Case Is = 3
ComboBox2.RowSource = "West"
End Select
End Sub
```

the output should be if Username(textbox1) = xyz then lookup all the teams from the lookup sheet that xyz manages and give a dropdown option of North and South defaulting with the first team.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code but I don't want to use 2 comboboxes I want just one combo box where the user can select the team they are managing, I don't want them to select themselves. I basically want to replace combox1 with environ(username) function.. sorry hope that makes sense

Comment: Seems like you've got a handle on the programming but not your data.  Have you considered reworking the data with power query and using that at as the row source?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean as they will be using the userform for data entry. example joe blogs opens userform who looks after 2 areas and selects the one hes working on from combobox1 and enters his numbers. then john wilson opens the userform who looks after 1 area and enters his numbers without the need to select  the area (combobox) as it wont give anymore options. thanks